# express tan(x) as a power series using maclauran's theorem.

Tags: trigonometry, derivatives, power-series

the theorem states that if f(x) can be expanded as a power series for a given range of values of x then:

$$f(x)=f(0)+xf'(0)+\frac{x^2}{2!}f''(0)+\frac{x^3}{3!}f'''(0)+\cdots$$

($'$ means derivative)
if $f(x)=\tan(x)$, what is the power series?

Answer (score 0):

The right name of the theorem -> [Taylor-McLaurin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series)

How to format equations on M.SE -> [Mathjax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

And an answer to your question (given by googling "mclaurin tan") -> [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MaclaurinSeries.html) (where $B_n$ is the $n$-th Bernoulli number)